# Cantor intersection theorem holds iff $(X, d)$ is a complete metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

My attempt: Assume that in $(X, d)$ the Cantor intersection theorem holds for all closed sets.

Assume for the sake of contradiction that $(X, d) $ is not complete then we have a Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$ is a Cauchy sequence which is not convergent.

Then the set $F_1= \{x_n\}$ is a closed set as $F_1$ doesn't have a limit point (if it does have a limit point then the sequence will be convergent).

Let $F_2= \{x_n\} - x_1$ and induction we can have $F_n = \{x_n\} - x_{n-1}$ so that each $F_n$ is closed and it is a nested sequence of closed sets.

Also by using the property of Cauchy sequence we can see that $diam(F_n) \to 0$. Hence $\cap_{n \ge 1}F_n$ isnonempty and contains a singleton element $x$ which is the limit of the sequence.

Hence the Cauchy sequence is convergent.

The other part is given in the book. Can someone go through this proof?

Comment: Nested sequence of 'intervals'?. Also,  the definition of $F_n$ is not clear.

Comment: Work with $F_n=\{x_n,x_{n+1},...\}$.